# Validar un tipo de dato al leerlo en C

Tags: c, validación, dev-c++

Quisiera saber la mejor forma y mas eficiente, de leer un tipo de dato y si digitan cualquier otra cosa que no pase de alli, hasta que digite el tipo de dato que le estoy pidiendo.

Ejemplo:

```
int numero;
printf("Digite un numero: ");
scanf("%d",&numero);
```

Si el usuario digita una letra, que no la acepte; si el usuario digita signos como: ., ´{[]}]#€~€€~~@#@| entre otros, que no lo acepte; lo mismo va para el tipo de dato `char`, al cual no he podido controlar muy bien porque este me acepta numeros y signos.

Lo que busco es que la lectura de datos sea bastante compacta y segura.

He esta implementando la siguiente sentencia para leer un tipo de dato en especifico pero me falta que no acepte los signos: .´{}{][~#@€@#€´ç`+`++`, etc.

```
      do //Utilizo un 'do-while' para validar el ingreso del tipo de dato.
    {       
        system("CLS");  
        printf("DIGITE EL NUMERO DE CONJUNTOS QUE DESEA CREAR (DEBE SER MAYOR A '0' - HASTA 20 ): ");
    }
    while(!scanf("%d",&vectores)==1 || vectores==0 || vectores>20);
```

Mientras que scanf no me devuelva 0, seguira alli; no sé si es la mejor forma pero me funciona muy bien ya que es la sentencia mas corta que he visto para validar un tipo de dato.

Comment: Así es como se hace, comprobando el retorno de `scanf( )`. No entiendo la pregunta.

Comment: Pero cuando quiero validar el tipo de dato char, y el usuario me digita numeros y signos , lo acepta

Comment: Claro, lógico. Un dígito sigue siendo un caracter. Deberías [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/162346/edit) e indicar exactamente lo que quieres hacer: **validar carácter a carácter**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilicé la función `isalpha` y `isdigit` de la libreria `<ctype.h>` para validar el tipo de dato.

Answer (score 2):

Debes capturar un caracter y comprobar si el caracter se corresponde con un numero,sino puedes crear una cadena de caracteres y comprobar dígito a dígito:

```
do{
    char numero;
    printf("Digite un numero: ");
    scanf("%c",&numero);
while(numero<'0'||numero>'9');
int numero2=atoi(numero);
```

En el ejemplo de cadenas de caracteres debes hacer un bucle con la cadena para comprobar dígito a dígito.

Comment: Disculpa, estas usando la variable numero afuera de su scope, ese codigo no funcionaria, aunque la logica es correcta

Answer (score 1):

Mira, para validar distintos tipos de datos suelen haber validaciones diferentes, asi que me acotaré a la segunda condición que hay en tu pregunta

> DEBE SER MAYOR A '0' - HASTA 20

Lo cual de hecho es bastante sencillo:

```
//buffer de lectura
char buffer[3];
//numero leido
int  n;
//Limpiamos el buffer
memset(buffer,0,3);
//Leemos exactamente dos caracteres del standar input
fread(buffer, 2, 1, stdin);
//Los convertimos a entero
n = atoi(buffer);
//Comprobamos el numero
if(n > 0 && n < 21){
    printf("OK");
}else{
    printf("NO");
}
```